# Find multiple words with regex in Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract those div with `beautifulsoup4` and regex expression in the `find_all()` method

```
<div class="prod roundedBox">
<div class="prod roundedBox last">
```

I've tried different possibilities but I can't get a working one for extract the tag using only the words *prod roundedBox*. I want to use both words! If I use one of them I take up other unwanted tags.

```
re.compile("prod.roundedBox")
re.compile("prod\sroundedBox.*")
```

are not working.

any idea!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) to find your results.

```
import bs4

html = '''
<div class="example">example</div>
<div class="prod roundedBox">foo</div>
<div class="prod roundedBox last">bar</div>
'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
soup(attrs={'class' : ['prod', 'roundedBox']})
```

If you wanted to use regular expression, here is an example:

```
import re
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
soup(attrs={'class' : re.compile(r'^prod')})
```

Output

```
[<div class="prod roundedBox">foo</div>, <div class="prod roundedBox last">bar</div>]
```

Comment: Always happy when I can avoid regex. Didn't get this possibility from the docs.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @UncleSax is if right [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters), but there is ALOT of options. `beautifulsoup4` looks so much easier then `perl`'s `HTML::TreeBuilder` which I have to use frequently.

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work to me this solution. are you using bs3?

Comment: @UncleSax Updated for bs4

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex.  This is what css selectors are for.

```
soup.select('div.prod.roundedBox')
```

You can grab whichever attributes you like, the above grabs anything with class `prod` and `roundedBox`.  See:

```
soup.select('div.prod.roundedBox')
Out[38]: [<div class="prod roundedBox"></div>, <div class="prod roundedBox last"></div>]

soup.select('div.prod.roundedBox.last')
Out[39]: [<div class="prod roundedBox last"></div>]
```